# Stretching from the top left when changing width & height wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, user-interface, grid, stretch

So I have a window that has a "drawer" of sorts. It slides out from behind the window when a user hits a button and it sits to the right of window.

The user can resize the main window (its a scatterview item specifically). I wanted to scale the "drawer" with the window. However, I'm running into an issue where when you resize the window it will resize the drawer from the top right out to the left. This puts the content of the drawer behind my window. I want to preserve the left portion of the window and stretch it out to the right. I hope my pictures explain it better.

(Note, please excuse the tab control position discrepency in both pictures, sorry)

This is before the grid with rectangle & tab control slides out:

[image: previous]

This is when the grid with rectangle & tab control has been slid out:

[image: step1]

This is when the scatterview item has been scaled larger, which thus scales the drawer larger - hiding it behind the scatterview item unintentionally:

[image: step2]

This is when the scatterview item has been scaled DOWN, which thus scales the drawer smaller. Its evident that the grid housing the rectangle and the tab control are scaling to the top right corner as opposed to the top left corner as I want.

[image: step3]

Does it have anything to do with the fact that I have the drawer height bounded to the height and width values of the main window somehow? I've tried all kinds of rightalignment values and stuff to no avail. Would a dock panel be suitable for this one tab control? Here is some of the XAML:

```
    <s:ScatterViewItem x:Name="Window" Orientation="0"
        Background="#FF787878" MaxWidth="500" MaxHeight="500" Center="9000,9000" CanScale="True" Visibility="Visible" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" Width="200" Height="150" >
   <!--Bunch of other items like textboxes here-->
        <Grid x:Name="HancockDetails" Height="{Binding ActualHeight, ElementName=grid1}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=grid1}" Grid.Column="1" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" FlowDirection="RightToLeft" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
        <Grid.RenderTransform>
          <TranslateTransform x:Name="hcDetailTransform" />
         </Grid.RenderTransform>
          <Rectangle>
          <TabControl>
              <TabItem>
                 <TextBlock>
                 </TextBlock>
              </TabItem>
           </TabControl>
           </Rectangle>
          </Grid>
    </Scatterviewitem>
```

Comment: Post your full xaml where you have these two control's, it's hard to guess the context with the info provided.

Comment: I guess I can try to truncuate it. The above is the layout. Theres a lot more individual items inbetween but I'm pretty sure they don't relate.

Comment: Even added additional picture to show how it scales down too.

Answer (score 0):

It's incredibly difficult for us to guess how you may have coded your UI, so without you providing some code, it's unlikely that we'll be able to find out what your exact problem is.

However, looking at this in a new way... I see a large rectangle in your screen shots. On the left of this rectangle is what you call your main window and on the right is... well, something else. I see that this rectangle has been rotated a small amount.

Can you not just make that outer rectangle a slightly rotated `Grid` with two columns; the main window in the left column and your other 'drawer' in the right column? Then, when the user resizes the window, the `Grid` will automatically fill the space and keep everything together.

Comment: I'm sorry, I had added more XAML code as previously asked for to the original post but it didn't format correctly. I've never seen that before on Stackoverflow where the code doesn't even appear as plain text! So sorry >.< I did mention that the box on the left is a Scatterview item. I should've also mentioned that the box on the right (or the "drawer" that moves) is a grid with a rectangle and tab control in it. The "rotation" is just scatterview from Surface SDK2.0 where you can touch, throw, rotate, scale boxes.

Comment: The box on the right, the drawer, which I'm having problems scaling needs to be a child of the box on the left because its a scatterview item. It automatically inherits the moves, rotates, flinging physics, and scaling when a user touches the box. And note that the box on the right is initially not visible, but slides out from behind the box on the left initially. I've added another picture to show this.